# Does every hero have a New Year's Resolution?

Tags: overwatch

While I was on playing on Oasis, after the New Year had already passed, Lucio surprised me with a voice line that said something like "My New Year's Resolution? Get new skates to all the kids on the block!".

Since then I haven't been able to trigger other hero's so-called "new year's resolutions". I'm not sure if I have to play specifically on Oasis, or if it triggers on any map, or any game mode.

Do all heroes have new year's resolutions? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nearly all the characters have indeed a line. Here are most of those:

- **D.Va**: "My New Year's resolution? Play all the games I need to catch up on!"
- **Zarya**: ["My new year's resolution? Five one three."](https://clyp.it/bq1txkwe) (Reference to her previous weight lifting record which was 512kg)
- **Zarya**: ["My new year's resolution? Peace on Earth."](https://clyp.it/gtzbnpi4)
- **Pharah**: ["My new year's resolution? Take some time off."](https://clyp.it/xlzsfun0)
- **Lucio**: ["My new year's resolution? Hmm. New skates for all the kids in the neighborhood."](https://clyp.it/fzafjqei)
- **Winston**: ["My new year's resolutions? Less peanut butter, more... bananas."](https://clyp.it/gdhwtajv)
- **Reaper**: ["This wasn't a good year for you."](https://clyp.it/kvzhh5zv)
- **Genji**: "あけましておめでとうございます", that you can read "Akemashite omedetou gozaimasu", that you can translate as "Happy New Year".
- **Mei**: ["My New Year’s resolution? Hmm… I could do a better job controlling my temper."](https://clyp.it/dtuo0i3m)
- **Widowmaker**: "New Year’s resolutions?", *Laughs*, "How precious."
- **Soldier 76**: "I stopped making New Year’s resolutions a long time ago."
- **Junkrat**: "My New Year’s resolution? I think I’d like to travel more."
- **Reinhardt**: "My New Year's resolution? Same as always! Fighting for justice!"

Possibly Unused

- **Mercy**: "Mercy always wanted to take time off work."
- **Sombra**: "New Year's resolution is 3840 x 2160."

Comment: X.X that sombra one is hilarious. Excessive, but hilarious. I wish she'd state the size of the display though.

Comment: The Japanese text only says "Akemashite omedetou" _(the ございます "gozaimasu" is optional, it just makes it sound more formal)_.  Which is actually played in the game?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Ah sorry, I forgot the ございます in the text. I'll add it. He does say it in his line. You can hear it [in this video](https://youtu.be/32H5Ns74Kds?t=3m40s).

Comment: @Isuka So just to confirm when you say "nearly".  This means heroes like Roadhog, Bastion, Mcree and the others not listed don't have NY resolution lines? And also why does Zarya have two?

Comment: @Memor-X, Pharah officially (by Blizzard canon) has a boyfriend, Mercy officially is in relationship with Genji.

Comment: @ʀᴇᴛʀᴏsᴀᴜʀ I think the second Zarya one is supposed to be Zenyatta.

Comment: That screen resolution joke is so old

Comment: What's, "Five one three" referring to? Either I'm missing something or it's just because I don't play.

Comment: @KizTrap She does say the two lines. You can hear those [here](https://clyp.it/gtzbnpi4) and [here](https://clyp.it/bq1txkwe).

Comment: @jpmc26 This is a reference to her previous weight lifting record, which is 512 kg. That means her goal this year is to beat this record and lift 513 kg.

Comment: @ʀᴇᴛʀᴏsᴀᴜʀ The "nearly" is because I am not sure if there are some lines I am missing, even if I didn't see any report of those. With the current build, it doesn't seem there is any line missing in this list though.  They might add some in some later build, but that is total speculation there. I have no idea why Zarya has more than one, but she even has a third one, which is a [long line](https://clyp.it/xxfhrt5a) said in Russian. But she apparently doesn't say it in game.

Comment: @Isuka Holy crumb buckets! Didn't realise Zarya was a pacifist..

Comment: @Isuka a pissifist?

Comment: @lentinant Where did you see that? AFAIK neither of those claims are officially true.

Comment: @MageXy New Year comic. Pharra dinners with someone, Genji writes letter, Mercy reads letter.

Comment: @lentinant Pharah is having dinner with someone clearly much older than her (he's got white streaks of hair) - it seems unlikely this is a boyfriend. The Overwatch subreddit believes whoever it is, it's probably her father. As for Genji/Mercy, writing a letter during the holidays hardly seems like proof that they are together. Remember that Mercy did save Genji's life... Given his character, he probably just wants to keep in touch to show how grateful he is.